# how to generate and save docx file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, docx

I tried `docx_template` but it won't work for me, thus anyone have experience in generating docx file and saving it.
When I tried docx_template it shows the error below. Can you give me a small example from docx_template. I have tried docxtpl but it uses some deprecated version of the packages.

> E/flutter (24648): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Could not find End of Central Directory Record

Comment: you can use PDF file

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
You can use pdf package for saving file in the internal storage.

Method 2:
You need to place a docx template in projet assets folder.
Every time you want to save docx file or doc you just have to replace your desired content with that docx template and save into internal storage.

Comment: any example(simple) code

Comment: @KumaresanJackie did you find anything?